# Check if a record defined using positional parameters

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Is there any way to distinguish a record defined using positional parameters from standard property syntax defined? (I need to check it for immutability)

```
public record Person1(string FirstName, string LastName);
```

vs

```
public record Person2
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
};
```

and the method would be like this:

```
bool DefinedUsingPositionalParameters(Type type) { ... } // Person1: true, Person2: false
```

Comment: One is meant to be shorthand for the other. Whatever you're *planning* to do by distinguishing between them, please reconsider and... don't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're right, but there is a difference, one of them is immutable. I need to check immutability.

Comment: They're both immutable. Using a primary constructor creates `get; init;` properties. The only difference there is one has a 2-arg ctor, and the other has a parameterless ctor

Comment: @canton7 I don't think so. check it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#immutability

Comment: @M.Khooryani I do think so, check it: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAASyRQAmpASgBQCWAdgC6kBiEEAlANxA. Also from the page you linked, "*Properties that you create by using positional syntax are immutable.*"

Comment: @canton7 yes it is. I don't have a problem with positional syntax, but the problem is the standard way, from that page: "You can declare properties with set accessors and fields that aren't readonly." that's why records are not immutable necessarily. am I wrong?

Comment: You *can* declare a record's properties with `set` accessors, but none of the code in your question does this. You're not asking how to distinguish a property with a set accessor from a property from an init accessor, your question asks how to distinguish a positional immutable record from a non-positional immutable record, and you claim that this is because you need to check for immutability. But both of the records in your question are immutable

Comment: There's no general way to tell whether a record, or any other type, is immutable. You can see if any of its properties have public setters, but that doesn't help if the record has a method which mutates one of its properties